# Setting different cellIdentifiers for each section in a UITableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have implemented the SWRevealController (a slide out menu), I referecned AppCoda.com for som help, here's the link (http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/).

I have succesfully implemented it, using the same way as AppCoda explains, setting cellIdentifiers for each cell in the sidebar and then styling them in the storyBoard. It all works great! However...

**THE PROBLEM**

So the problem is that I want sections in this table view, so that I can have different cells in different sections, but using the code I have now (which is below), I just get a repeated cell (the same cells as in my first section). I am having trouble with the sections because styling each cell based on their cell identifier.

This is what I get...

**SO MY RESOLUTION (THAT DIDN'T WORK)**

So what I tried to do was create multiple arrays, one for each section, and styled them like this,

```
  if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [_fitnessItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"torso-25.png"];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"weightlift-25.png"];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"barbell-25.png"];
    }
   }
```

But it worked, and I got what I wanted, however, it was very gilitchy when I tried to do an action when a cell was pressed, I was doing that like this...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath{

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"test" sender:nil];
}
```

Now there might do be a way to fix this issue or fix the cell identifiers. Anyways that's what I tried doing.

**WHAT I AM DOING NOW**

So if you don't quite understand what I am doing, check out that AppCoda tutorial cause thats what I did. But I want sections between some cells. What I tried doing is this and it dosen;t work...

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [self.fitnessItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

else {
NSString *CellIdentifier = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

So I have two arrays of cell Identifiers and I try to allocate them to each section, but it dosen't work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to clarify exactly what ti is you're trying to do. the answer rmaddy gave answered the question you have in your title. Do you want different identifiers for every cell, no repeats between sections? Same row in each section to have the same kind of cell? BTW, the method you showed that you used to do an action on cell press is didDeselect, instead of didSelect -- is that a typo, or do you really have that?

Comment: thanks, didDeselect, simple error, however I now get a error saying index 1 bounds beyonds [0,0] any thoughts? @rdelmar